# How to bind workspace to shortcut, and also bind return to previous workspace to the same key

Tags: spaces

Basically I imagine it like this:
I am on workspace 5, I press "shortcut" and it moves me to set workspace number 8 (or something). When I am done, I press the same shortcut and it moves me to workspace 5 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts sets keyboard shortcuts for all Desktops to `CTRL n` (where n is the number of the Desktop).

[image]

However, they are disabled by default. So it would be very easy to press `CTRL 8` and `CTRL 5` to switch between Desktops. If you wanted the same shortcut for both actions, you would have to use some kind of script to check the current Desktop setting and make the appropriate move.